# Поднять scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Как можно по нажатию кнопки поднять скролл в самое начало блока?
скролл сделан через overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button if="toTop">Наверх</button>

var toTop = document.getElementById('toTop');
toTop.onclick = function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div class='top'>Крутите вниз!</div>

<div style='height: 200px'></div>
<button><a href='#top'>Наверх!</a></button>
```

Можно также без кнопок, просто по нажатию на ссылку:

```html
<div class='top'>Крутите вниз!</div>

<div style='height: 200px'></div>
<a href='#top'>Наверх!</a>
```